Flutter Image Picker Error. What file type do I set Image to
I am having a null error. I am trying to setup an image picker for my profile edit page. What file type do I make imageFile and what initial value do I assign to it. Here is my code below:
  //Photo Picker variables
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  var imageFile = null;

  //Select image from phone gallery
  chooseImage() async {
    XFile? file = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (file != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(file.path);
      });
    }
 }


cant think of issue but you can try File? imageFile;

Why don't you use XFile?
